# How to split pandas dataframe column to matrix of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide column of lists to x (number of unique values) columns with 1 if exists in row and 0 if it doesn't
For example:

```
         animals
0  dog;mouse;cat
1        cat;dog
2            dog
3      mouse;cat
4        dog;cat
```

to:

```
   dog  mouse  cat
0    1      1    1
1    1      0    1
2    1      0    0
3    0      1    1
4    1      0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df['animals'].str.get_dummies(sep=';')
```

output:

```
   cat  dog  mouse
0    1    1      1
1    1    1      0
2    0    1      0
3    1    0      1
4    1    1      0
```